# AngularJs How to Set Absolute Urls with $location?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, location, url-routing

I have a site where I have

sitename.com/path1/path2

and I want to change path1 through angularJS. I can change path2 with $location.path function but am wondering what to use to change a specific part of the url or set an absolute url as $location.path and $location.url only change the last parameter.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at $location.url it provides the ability to replace segments of the url. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$location